# How to have a view in ipad just like Appstore

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I want to have a view in my application to be displayed just like app store showing application.

I mean a view in middle of page, smaller than iPad actual size, and the rest of view is dimmed.

just like this:

[image]

should i use modal or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From code:

```
myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you use storyboard you can also set modal segue with FormSheet style.